# Webpack: keep hashes of unchanged files

Tags: javascript, webpack

We have a very large JS codebase which uses Webpack to generate chunks, which are then deployed to an S3 bucket.

We use the standard Webpack hash system to make each filename unique for each build. However, this leads to situations where smaller changes effectively lead to a large number of new chunks being produced, despite their content being identical to that of their counterparts in the previous build. In effect, the users browser will skip cache to fetch a file it technically already has.

What I would like to know is if there is any way for Webpack to maintain some kind of manifest between build, keeping hashes the same for generated files whose content has not changed since the last build.

Comment: Have you seen this: https://github.com/mzgoddard/hard-source-webpack-plugin?

Comment: Genuinely an open question... does it matter as long as you cache the next set of generated files on a CDN for the next requests that come through?